# How to hide play symbol of video autoplay of ionic app?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

So, I have a video playing on the background of an Ionic app. However, when it starts playing, the play symbol appears. [Click here to see a video of what happens](https://streamable.com/jeh0y9)

As you can see, before playing the video, this [symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFQYx.png) pops up and I want to hide it.

Html:

```
<ion-header [translucent]="true">
  <ion-toolbar color="dark">
    <ion-title style="text-align: center;">
      mDL
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content [fullscreen]="true">
  <video class="video" autoplay muted loop>
    <source src="http://grochtdreis.de/fuer-jsfiddle/video/sintel_trailer-480.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</ion-content>
```

CSS:

```
.video {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  object-fit: fill;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

### **Solution:**

Add `poster="noposter"` to video element.
Example:

```
  <video poster="noposter" class="video" autoplay muted loop>
    <source src="http://grochtdreis.de/fuer-jsfiddle/video/sintel_trailer-480.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
```

Comment: No, but it mentions another thread that had the solution! Thanks!
Basically I have to had `poster="noposter"` to the video element.

Comment: If you found an alternate answer you should add it to the duplicate, not to your question.